# How to figure out in Redux enviroment

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

Im new in frontend developer.
And i started to learn Redux toolkit.
In Redux Toolkit we have a function -- createAsyncThunk.

But also i heard about Redux Thunk.
Is Redux Toolkit already included Redux Thunk, or this two approaches are different?
I will be glad if you give me some topic or documentation abouit this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. RTK adds `react-thunk` middleware by default, see [Included Default Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#included-default-middleware).

> In addition to these development tool middleware, it also adds `redux-thunk` by default, since thunks are the basic recommended side effects middleware for Redux.